# Debugging a java jar file

Tags: java, debugging

I have a jar file and i don't have source. It should connect to a server. It doesn't run at the first time and i need to run it second time. I am trying to find a way to get it's logs. How can i enable it's logs?

Here is how i call it

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -jar mcon.jar
```

I have found and tried the code below but i think it is for server sockets

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n -jar mcon.jar
```

Comment: You could try running the code in debug mode, which might let you find the exact line which is failing.

Comment: How can i do that? I am not a java programmer but i am trying to findout the problem

Answer (score 1):

what you found is mostly correct but you do not need the address , that is to do remote debugging to connect to server

from command line , what you need is

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,address=jdbconn,server=y,suspend=n -jar mcon.jar
```

then you can connect java debugger

```
jdb -attach jdbconn
```

you can refer to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) to find out the command you can use

Comment: here is what i have got
ERROR: transport library not found: dt_shmem
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_shmem failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_LOAD(509)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196)
./debug.sh: line 8:  7938 Aborted                 java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,address=jdbconn,server=y,suspend=n -jar mcon.jar

Comment: do you have JDK installed or only JRE ? looks like you have only JRE you would need the full JDK to run debugger

Comment: I have both versions. 6 and 7

Comment: But i can use dt_socket if that helps?

Comment: weird, make sure you run the java from the JDK 7

Comment: dt_socket will connect to the particular port but if your programm does not run on this port, nothing will happen and the debugger will not connect

Comment: I know i have it but can not find 7

Comment: Ok i have found the installed folder and i still have this error